# How do I switch back to having /dev/shm be the mount point instead of /run/shm?

Tags: 11.10, mount, oracle

I am using 11.10 and have an application (oracle xe) which specifically wants shared memory mounted under /dev/shm.  I noticed that the way 11.10 is configured, things are mounted at /run/shm and symlinked from /dev/shm.

I can get things to work by running hte following as root

1. # Kill all apps that are using /run/shm
2. umount /run/shm
3. rmdir /run/shm
4. unlink /dev/shm
5. mkdir /dev/shm
6. mount /dev/shm # I have it defined in /etc/fstab
7. ln -s /dev/shm /run/shm

But whenever I reboot, everything goes back to the way that ubuntu ships.  What do I need to change to get ubuntu to not try and mount /run/shm?

Thanks,
Ransom

Comment: It specifically checks that the actual mountpoint is `/dev/shm`? If it merely needs read/write access, then the symlink "should" be fine. If it actually checks `/etc/mtab`, then that's weird and more complicated. Could you show your `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: Also, take a look at [this post on the Oracle forums](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2298493). It seems to be about this exact issue. Post an answer if that solves your problem so that others can benefit from it.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!